# Permissions error with wordpress

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, wordpress

So recently I had migrated my site to amazon Vps and getting too many permissions errors.

**I have already changed all folder permissions to > 755 and all file to > 644.**

**Also, given chown of wp-upload to www-data.**

But I still can't upload files to WP site, and also plugins too, showing permission error (can't make dir).

What I have done wrong here?

**UPDATE:**

" ls -lZ " for wp-content

```
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data ?  596 Mar 30 05:36 advanced-cache.php
drwxr-xr-x 10 www-data www-data ? 4096 Mar 28 21:11 cache
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data ? 1399 Mar 28 21:10 db.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data ?   28 Jan  8  2012 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data ? 4517 Mar 28 21:10 object-cache.php
drwxr-xr-x 45 www-data www-data ? 4096 Apr  3 13:48 plugins
drwxr-xr-x  7 www-data www-data ? 4096 Apr  3 13:48 themes
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data ? 4096 Mar 28 21:53 updraft
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data ? 4096 Mar 28 23:00 upgrade
drwxr-xr-x 10 www-data www-data ? 4096 Dec 31 18:31 uploads
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data ? 4096 Mar 28 22:33 w3tc-config
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data ? 4096 Mar 30 05:36 wp-rocket-config
```

Comment: what errors can you see in the logs?

Comment: @Jakuje writing error probably! when installing Wordpress plugin it says "Failed: Could not create directory" and on uploading media it says "The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads"

Comment: What permissions does `wp-content/uploads` have?  Show the output using `ls -lZ wp-content/uploads`.

Comment: @val0x00ff 
for upload folder ""
drwxr-xr-x 10 www-data www-data ? 4096 Dec 31 18:31 uploads ""

Comment: @PrashantGupta please edit the question and show exactly what it looks like. Also `ls -lZ` will return `SELinux context labels`

Comment: @val0x00ff updated

Comment: @PrashantGupta what are the logs saying?  Have you checked apache logs?  THey might give you detailed clues.

Comment: Have you double-checked that apache is running as the www-data user?  maybe a long shot but it's configurable (and varies by distro what is default)

Comment: @adam i ve been working with vestacp i don't know it it changed  the default user !?

Comment: It might well be the right user, but check the httpd.conf to be certain. The conf file should be under /etc/apache2 or /etc/httpd/conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give www-data -group read/write/execute rights to wp-content and **all subdirectories**.

Eg:

```
chmod -R 775 wp-content
```

Comment: it works, but i just wanted to know is 775 safe?

Comment: Safe depends on the server and configurations, but since you're on Amazon Virtual **Private** server, it should be A) safe and B) necessary.